# How to implement post-processing in Apache Superset 1.5.0

Tags: python, apache-superset

I am currently working on extending the current Apache Superset 1.5.0 version by a custom implementation of an anonymized column configuration (as seen in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBWEX.png)). The intended idea is, that if a column in the dataset-editor is set to be anonymized, then superset should query the data as they are from the database but *before* sending them to the frontend, the particular column(s) should be anonymized.

I am already able to store that checkbox value in the database, since I am not familiar with the backend implementation, I don't know where to put the concrete implementation of the anonymization function.

I already found that the query result can be post-processed in `query_context_processor.py`, but how do I get the information then if a column is set to be anonymized?

[image: New column configuration]

Answer (score 1):

This is not something trivial, and relying on post-processing wouldn't be safe — it could be easily bypassed by a malicious user, since post-processing is a request from the client side.

I believe the proper way to do this would be to extend the [column model](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/ce547f4098f54f048d744c5d09200fb694979a48/superset/columns/models.py#L38) and add the `anonymized` attribute to it. Note that there is an [ongoing effort](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/14909) to update the column model (along with other models), which complicates things a little bit, since you might need to also add the logic to the [old model](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/ce547f4098f54f048d744c5d09200fb694979a48/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py#L225) until the migration is complete. With this you would be able to determine which columns in a given dataset would need to be anonymized, and you could replace them with a function when the query object is built.

If you have only a few columns that you want to anonymize one way to do is creating a virtual dataset that has the anonymized column, and give access only to that dataset to the users, and not the underlying table. For example, you could write the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  user_id, user_username, HASH(user_email) AS anonymized_email, ...
FROM ...
...
```

And then save it as a virtual dataset.

Comment: Since you already meant that there a) is ongoing effort on the column model and b) that I'd need to add logic to the old model, I don't think in general it would be the best idea for me to change stuff in superset directly. The last idea I had was to fake the data already while parsing and provide a public user which then gets the anonymized dataset as shown in here [How to change the dataset used in charts based on the user connected](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUPvFfUv29U). What's your opinion on that?